# pgf install error - MiKTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, miktex

i have this code taken from another question trying to produce a tree:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
-- +(0,-8pt)
-| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix
{
\node{\Tree
    [.Class  \edge[color=white]; 
    [.Order  \edge[color=white];
    [.Family \edge[color=white]; 
    [.Genus ]]]]};
&
\node{\Tree 
 [.{$\gamma$-proteobacteria} 
    [.Alteromonadales 
        [.Alteromonadaceae  {Glaciecola}  Alteromonas Agarivorans ] ]
    [.Vibrionales [.Vibrionacae Vibrio ]]]};\\
};           
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but when compiling using TeXworks in MiKTeX 2.9 i always get the same error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/nagi/Desktop/these/myLaTeX/these.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
an, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, 
romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tikz-qtree\tikz-qtree.sty"
======================================================================
pdflatex.EXE: Cannot start MiKTeX package manager.
pdflatex.EXE: Data: The class is not configured to support Elevated activation.

======================================================================


! LaTeX Error: File `tikz.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

can you help me solve this issue, i really need to draw some trees in my thesis...
thank you.

EDIT:
as requested by Alan Munn, i tried to install pgf from the package manager, and received this error at the end of the download process:

```
MiKTeX Problem Report Message: The operation could not be completed because the following file failed verification: C:\Users\nagi\AppData\Local\Temp\mik2E71.tmp
```

i tried installing pgf again after some time, but with the same result (error).

Comment: This really seems to have nothing to do with `tikz-qtree` but everything to do with MikTeX.  Can you use the MikTeX package manager manually to install `tikz` and `tikz-qtree`?  See this question: [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/2693)

Comment: @Alan: i used the package manager and installed tikz-qtree but couldn't find tikz anywhere...

Comment: @Nagi Try installing `pgf` instead.

Comment: @Alan: got the same error twice when trying to install pgf:"MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: The operation could not be completed because the following file failed verification:

C:\Users\nagi\AppData\Local\Temp\mik2E71.tmp"

Comment: @Nagi, sorry I can't help you more on that. (I use a Mac.) I would completely edit your question to be something like "MikTeX gives me an error when I try to install pgf", and explain what you've done, and the error you receive. That way more MikTeX users might notice the question and be able to help you.

Comment: @Alan: thank you. i will edit it as soon as i can.

Comment: @Nagi: It seems there is a problem with pgf in miktex's repositories. Look at http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=C6936EDE652538489B6B011B2B630CFD228386BB%40EXMBX07.netplexity.local&forum_name=miktex-users and http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=C6936EDE652538489B6B011B2B630CFD22830EF3%40EXMBX07.netplexity.local&forum_name=miktex-users. I'm sorry I don't know how two 'hide' this links.

Comment: It looks as if the pgf-package is corrupted. There already exist a bug report and it will hopefuly be corrected soon. You can try to find an "outdated" repository which still has an older version and use this to install pgf http://www.miktex.org/pkg/repositories.

Comment: @Ulrike & @Ignasi: i found an old pgf package and installed it. the error above was solved, but i stumbled upon another one, which is very similar to the previous one. "LaTeX Error: File `everyshi.sty' not found." can you tell me which package should i install now? thank you

Comment: everyshi is in the "ms" package.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. There is a solution?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. This is an question and answer site and differs from a normal forum. Please only post solutions in the answer section. I convert your post to an answer to keep it tidy. By design new users can't comment on other question to protect the side from spam bots etc. You need 50rep points for this. Also the question is only 15 hours old so just give it a little more time. Should it be caused by MikTeX the MikTeX forum might also a good place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you all! With your feedback I was able get this example to run.
I googled and installed manually the packages `pgf` and `ms` using the package manager. Hope MiKTeX will fix their repositories soon...